# What's the meaning of the numbered placeholders in ingress rewrite-target?

Tags: regex, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

For example, the following manifest(from https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/), I know that any characters captured by (.*) will be assigned to the placeholder $2, which is then used as a parameter in the rewrite-target annotation, but why it is $2, not $1 and $3? I can't find anything explaining the difference on the Internet.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
```

Comment: In a regex, every part of it in parentheses `()` is considered a group and each is numbered. Group 0 is the entire match, group 1 the first group, etc. So, in `/something(/|$)(.*)`, whatever matches `(/|$)` is group 1 and whatever matches `(.*)` is group 2. `$2` just refers to group to of whatever was matched for it.

Comment: @Grismar great answer, would you mind posting it in answers section?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In a regex, every part of it in parentheses `()` is considered a group and each is numbered. Group 0 is the entire match, group 1 the first group, etc.

So, in `/something(/|$)(.*)`, whatever matches `(/|$)` is group 1 and whatever matches `(.*)` is group 2. In your example, `$2` just refers to group 2 of whatever was matched for it and will be replaced by that.

Comment: So what happens if rewrite value is `/$1/$2`. For example, host is `host: api.mydomain.vn`, path is `/(api/v\\d)/demo/(.*)`, request is `https://api.mydomain.vn/api/v2/demo/emailing/abc/xyz`, it should be `http://emailing/abc/xyz`, right?

Comment: It's unclear in what language or context you are looking to use this regex and as a result it's impossible to say. Please don't post new questions as comments on old questions, but post a new question if you feel existing answers don't provide an answer. If anything,, I'd expect the outcome to be `/api/v2/emailing/abc/xyz`, but like I said,  you don't provide sufficient context and shouldn't follow up in the comments.

Comment: I dont know what you mean. It's totally related to your answer. `/$2` vs `/$1/$2`

Comment: Please reread my comment. There's no assertion there that it's unrelated. It does say that it's misplaced, incomplete, unclear, and ineffectual - nevermind not helpful to others. Please post a separate question if you need an answer, instead of arguing in the comments where you won't find what you need. If there's something to add to the answer, or something wrong with it, please point that out - that's what the comments are for.